# Reshape data into 'closest square'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to python.  Currently using matplotlib I have a script that returns a variable number of subplots to make, that I pass to another script to do the plotting.  I want to arrange these subplots into a nice arrangement, i.e., 'the closest thing to a square.' So the answer is unique, let's say I weight number of columns higher

Examples: Let's say I have 6 plots to make, the grid I would need is 2x3.  If I have 9, it's 3x3.  If I have 12, it's 3x4.  If I have 17, it's 4x5 but only one in the last row is created.

Attempt at a solution:  I can easily find the closest square that's large enough:

```
    num_plots = 6
    square_size = ceil(sqrt(num_plots))**2
```

But this will leave empty plots.  Is there a way to make the correct grid size?

Answer (score 2):

This what I have done in the past

```
num_plots = 6
nr = int(num_plots**0.5)
nc = num_plots/nr
if nr*nc < num_plots:
    nr+=1
fig,axs = pyplot.subplots(nr,nc,sharex=True,sharey=True)
```

Comment: This is almost correct - except if we have an odd number, there will be empty plots at the end of the grid.  Any way to prevent those?

Comment: Empty grid spots can be useful for adding legends; as well @EL_DON is right that prime numbers of plots will never divide up equally into more than one row or column.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a prime number of plots like 5 or 7, there's no way to do it unless you go one row or one column. If there are 9 or 15 plots, it should work.

The example below shows how to

- Blank the extra empty plots
- Force the axis pointer to be a 2D array so you can index it generally even if there's only one plot or one row of plots
- Find the correct row and column for each plot as you loop through

Here it is:

```
nplots=13
#find number of columns, rows, and empty plots
nc=int(nplots**0.5)
nr=int(ceil(nplots/float(nc)))
empty=nr*nc-nplots
#make the plot grid
f,ax=pyplot.subplots(nr,nc,sharex=True)

#force ax to have two axes so we can index it properly
if nplots==1:
    ax=array([ax])
if nc==1:
    ax=ax.reshape(nr,1)
if nr==1:
    ax=ax.reshape(1,nc)

#hide the unused subplots
for i in range(empty): ax[-(1+i),-1].axis('off')

#loop through subplots and make output
for i in range(nplots):
    ic=i/nr #find which row we're on. If the definitions of ir and ic are switched, the indecies for empty (above) should be switched, too.
    ir=mod(i,nr) #find which column we're on
    axx=ax[ir,ic] #get a pointer to the subplot we're working with
    axx.set_title(i)
```

[image: Example result using nplots=1, nplots=3, and nplots=13]

Comment: If we have a prime, like 7 for example, we would hope the output be 2x4, and not include the the last entry on the second row

Comment: @user6605695 You can have 2x4 with one empty or you can have 1x7. The alternative would be to have 2x3 + one double sized plot, but the logic for that would be longer.

Comment: Do you just want to have an empty space instead of unused axes? ```f,ax=plt.subplots(4,2)
ax[-1,-1].axis('off')```

Comment: empty space is the right idea - now just need a way to be able to set more than just the last one as 'off'.  like `ax[all not used, all not used].axis('off')`